# CMAKE 3.28.1 "(get_target_property): get_target_property called with incorrect number of arguments" with three arguments

Tags: cmake

I'm getting this error on CMake 3.28.1 on this line

```
get_target_property(APPLICATION_INCLUDES ${LIB_APPLICATION_TARGET_NAME} INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)
```

Thought the error is not really esplicative, and the get_target_property call is performed correctly on the following line

```
get_target_property(PLATFORM_INCLUDES ${LIB_PLATFORM_TARGET_NAME} INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)
```

Also, when I cloned the project earlier (I had to reclone recently) the CMakeList.txt was the same, but I did not get the error (same CMake version as well).
I can I get more information on this error?

Comment: Most likely, `LIB_APPLICATION_TARGET_NAME` variable is not set (or empty). That is, `get_target_property` is actually called with two arguments instead of three. Note, that in the second call you use other variable - `LIB_PLATFORM_TARGET_NAME`.